# Splitting a string in Java,

Tags: java, string, split, java.util.scanner, arrays

I am trying to split a string into a string array, but when it splits the string only the
first part, before the split, is in the array in the [0] slot, but nothing is in [1] or later. This also returns a java exception error when it tries to output spliced[1]

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class splittingString
{

    static String s;


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the length and units with a space between them");
        s = input.next();
        String[] spliced = s.split("\\s+");
        System.out.println("You have entered " + spliced[0] + " in the units of" + spliced[1]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: Have you verified that the input is what you expect it to be.

Comment: I have tried splitting with "\\s" and " " same problem, if you print out the length of the array it is always 1

Comment: try using a tokenizer and a loop and assign each token to the array http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: If the length of the array is 1 then it only has an element in spliced[0], and trying to access spliced[1] will throw you an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Could you print s so we know what it is?

Comment: "10 cm" is an input I test with

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use: -

```
input.nextLine()
```

Currently, you are using next which will return space delimeted

Comment: My pleasure, you can see some other methods in the javadocs that would allow you to read both 'spliced' results without having to call split. i.e. input.nextDouble() and input.next()

Answer (score 5):

`input.next()` reads a single word not a whole line(i.e. will stop at the first space). To read a whole line use `input.nextLine()`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your input is `12 34`, the content of the `s` variable is `12`, not `12 34`. You should use `Scanner.nextLine()` to read whole line.

Answer (score 3):

The problems is not with the `split()` function call. Rather the problem is with the function that you are using to read the input from the console.

`next()` only reads the first word that you type (basically does not read after the first space it encounters).

Instead use `nextLine()`. It would read the whole line (including spaces).

Here the corrected code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringSplit {

    static String s;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out
                .println("Enter the length and units with a space between them");
        s = input.nextLine();
        String[] spliced = s.split("\\s+");
        System.out.println("You have entered " + spliced[0]
                + " in the units of" + spliced[1]);

    }

}
```

Comment: @Arpit lol I was actually writing it when you commented. too fast :P

Comment: i'm in hurry in upvoting each correct ans. and swtching to next question. ;)